# Any API for MS Graph/AAD to add users to tenant as guests, without invite email?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any API, that allows the ability in app context or app+user context, to directly guest a user into a tenant without going through the invitation/redemption workflow?

I see this, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation, it shows how to suppress the email but it still forces a manual redemption process.

And it looks like the graph API only has "Create User", no "Add Guest".  User does have a field userType that could be "Guest", but it seems like this API is geared toward creating *new* users, so my hunch is this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement:-
User User1 is trying to invite users from Tenant-B to Tenant-A. The requirement is that there should not be any manual redemption process and redemption should happen automatically.

Solution:-
Add the user User1 to the Tenant-B as a member user (UserType == Member). Now user1 can invite any user from Tenant-B to Tenant-A with out forcing manual redemption.

In the invite API set sendInvitationMessage = false to avoid sending the invitation email.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation

Comment: Are you certain of this?  Because the documentation seems to imply otherwise.  It says `sendInviationMessage=false` only suppresses the email, so you can send your own redemption communication, but that manual redemption is still required in order to complete the process.